# How to access http array parameters in Django?

Tags: php, python, django, httprequest

**SCENARIO 1**

The following are my http request parameters

**PHP REQUEST**:

```
localhost/test.php?cars['key_1']=Saab&cars['key_2']=Audi
```

If I do a `print_r($_GET)` in php, i get the following response.

```
Array
(
    [cars] => Array
        (
            ['key_1'] => Saab
            ['key_2'] => Audi
        )

)
```

**DJANGO REQUEST**:

```
localhost/test/?cars['key_1']=Saab&cars['key_2']=Audi
```

while, in Django, on passing the same parameters, and on doing a 
`print(request.GET)`, I get

```
<QueryDict: {"cars['key_1']": ['Saab'], "cars['key_2']": ['Audi']}>
```

---

**SCENARIO 2**

Again, if I do the requests without the keys, like

**PHP REQUEST**:

```
localhost/v2/test.php?cars[]=Saab&cars[]=Audi

Array
(
    [cars] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => Audi
        )

)
```

**DJANGO REQUEST**:

```
localhost/test/?cars=Saab&cars=Audi

<QueryDict: {'cars': ['Saab', 'Audi']}>
```

Now, the question is `scenario 2` is working perfectly, but, how do I make `scenario 1` work in Django, so that I get something like. Like how in php, i get an associative array, will I get a key-value dictionary in Django?

```
<QueryDict: {'cars': {'key_1':'Saab', 'key_2':'Audi'}}>
```

Is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

No. Querydicts do not work like that.

The closest you can get is to post a nested object as JSON and decode it from `request.body`.